# Arrow Function not Working with outer variable

Tags: javascript

I apologize for my ignorant. I just started learning Javascript and I am on DOM manipulation and Event. MY question may not be up to standard

I am writing a code that receives value from  `input` and converts it uppercase. Here is my JS code.

> This doesn't work for me

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
let val = document.querySelector('#amount').value;

let uppercase = () => {
let newvalue =  val.toUpperCase();
console.log(newvalue)
let result = document.querySelector('.result');
result.innerHTML = newvalue;
}
```

> This work for me

```
let uppercase = () => {
const form = document.querySelector('form');
let val = document.querySelector('#amount').value;
let newvalue =  val.toUpperCase();
console.log(newvalue)
let result = document.querySelector('.result');
result.innerHTML = newvalue;
}
```

I don't want to follow this method as I want it to be re-usable.

> HTML

```
<form class="form-inline" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
    <div class="form-group mb-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount">
    </div>

     <button class="btn calculate-btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="uppercase()">Upper Case</button>
     <button class="btn calculate-btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="lowercase()">Lower Case</button>

</form>
   <div class="result">

   </div>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I just started learning on Monday.

Comment: The input is empty on pageload

Comment: What's the way around it, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be reusable then you can simply register a click event on elements having a given class and update their contents accordingly

```js
const uppercase = (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = event.currentTarget.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
}

const lowercase = (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = event.currentTarget.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
}

document.querySelectorAll('.uppercase').forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', uppercase);
});

document.querySelectorAll('.lowercase').forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', lowercase);
});
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
    <div class="form-group mb-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount">
    </div>

     <button class="btn calculate-btn btn-primary mb-2 uppercase">Upper Case</button>
     <button class="btn calculate-btn btn-primary mb-2 lowercase">Lower Case</button>

</form>
   <div class="result">

   </div>
```

Of course, if you decide to use the class to input elements then you must check it accordingly and change the value instead of innerHTML

Comment: FYI there's no need to do `[].forEach.call`. `nodelist.forEach` will work fine.

Comment: @Andy it doesn't work. I tried it before writing this piece of code

Comment: Ah, maybe it just works for `querySelectorAll` rather than `getElementsByClassName`. iirc they return different types of things.

Comment: @Andy yep.. updated the answer as it is much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix this

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');

let val = document.querySelector('#amount');
const btnup = document.querySelector('.up-btn')

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    btnup.addEventListener('click', () => {
        newval = val.value
        let newvalue =  newval.toUpperCase();
        newval == newvalue
        console.log(newvalue)
        let result = document.querySelector('.result');
        result.innerHTML = newvalue;
        })
});
```

> HTML

```
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount">
        </div>

         <button class="btn up-btn btn-primary mb-2">Upper Case</button>
         <button class="btn calculate-btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="lowercase()">Lower Case</button>

    </form>
       <div class="result">

       </div>
```